# CSS: auto adjust width to wrapping text content?

Tags: css, text

How does one adjust the width of an element to only be as wide as its content, including when a line of text wraps due to a fixed outer wrapper width.

Notice in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/vv9jce5j/2/) that the yellow background on each div is snug to its text content, *except* the one whose text wraps, in which case, the width of that div extends to the width of the outer wrapper.

What's the solution?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">apple</div>
  <div class="text">banana peels shouldn't be green</div>
  <div class="text">kiwi</div>
  <div class="text">orange</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty kludgy but I think it'll do what you want:

```css
.wrapper {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 115px;
}

.text {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.text:after { content: ' '; display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">apple</div>
  <div class="text">banana peels shouldn't be green</div>
  <div class="text">kiwi</div>
  <div class="text">orange</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can use js to add <br> if the length is too long, no css needed, and this way there will be no extra width. Then in the html just use `<div [innerHTML]="myText"></div>`.

Comment: Assuming your text is "myText" (short variable names because of char limit):

`myText = fixTextWidth(myText)

fixTextWidth() {
let ret = ""
let splittxt = myText.split(" ")
if(splittxt.length==0 || myText.length<=25) {
 ret = myText
}
if(myText.length>25) {
 let width=0;
 for(let i=0;i<splittxt.length;i++) {
  width = width+splittxt[i].length
  if(width<25) {
   ret=ret+splittxt[i]+ " "
  }else{
   ret=ret+"<br>"+splittxt[i]+ " "
  }
 }
}
return ret
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS method to adjust width of block to wrapped text length.
So you have two options here:

1. Resort to `text-align: justify`. In this case it would remove space to the right.
2. Use JavaScript to wrap all `div`s words in `span`s, then calculate X coordinate (`left` relative to parent + outer `width`) of `span` with the biggest X coordinate. Then based on this biggest X coordinate you should set `padding-right` or `width` or `margin-right` of your destination block.